# Can I decorate a method using custom attribute class to Auto re-try

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple c# method, If any exception thrown in the middle, i want to re-run/continue the method after some time (i.e 2 minutes) until it gets completed. for example if any exception occurs inside this for loop, i want to run this method after some configurable time, instead of throwing exception

```
  public void Process(List<string> msg)
  {
      foreach(var m in msg) {  }
  }
```

By decorating Something Like this

```
 [ReRun(Maxtime =5, TimeIntervalInSec=600)]
  public void Process(List<string> msg)
   {
      foreach(var m in msg) {  }
   }
```

Can it be done in as a Separate class, and plugged as a Attribute to this method?

Comment: "Insanity: doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results." - Albert Einstein

Comment: Attributes are just metadata, they do not impact the usage of the element they are attached to at all.

Comment: It is possible. You can write a custom method to run it, but it will be ugly.

Comment: The questioner is looking for a way to keep retry logic out of a function, which is good because the function should just do its thing and not be concerned with how many times it gets executed. An attribute might not be the best way, but it's still a valid problem to solve. It's true that whatever fails once will probably fail again and it's better to just fix that. But there are scenarios where we have to deal with buggy, unreliable services we can't control.

Comment: Exactly, My first intention of keeping code aside of actual method is to make my business logic code more cleaner. Also the chances of failure i couldn't fix is that some network failures and external service which is related to infrastructure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing that I would modify the caller to call the method again if it throws an exception. The Single Responsibility Principle suggests that it isn't the job of a class to manage how it gets called or what the caller does if it throws an exception. (But you already saw that because you avoided putting it directly in the method.)

I wrote this and did a few quick unit tests. (I'm lousy at naming things.) The usage is

```
var execution = new RetryExecution<int>(() => SomeFunctionThatReturnsAnInt());
var result = execution.Execute(2); //specifies maximum number of attempts.
```

It calls the given method *n* times and returns either the value or throws the last exception. The `Exceptions` property returns any unthrown exceptions.

```
public class RetryExecution<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T> _function;
    private List<Exception> _exceptions = new List<Exception>();

    public RetryExecution(Expression<Func<T>> expression )
    {
        _function = expression.Compile();
    }

    public Exception[] Exceptions { get { return _exceptions.ToArray(); } }

    public T Execute(int maxAttempts)
    {
        var attempts = 0;
        while (attempts < maxAttempts)
        {
            attempts++;
            try
            {
                return _function.Invoke();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (attempts >= maxAttempts) throw;
                _exceptions.Add(ex);
            }
        }
        return default(T);//Not reachable, but compiler needs it.
    }
}
```

Comment: One caveat - if anyone were to use something like this I'd hope to see a comment giving a good reason. I'd hate to see someone write some buggy code, like something that does some evil multithreading, and then wrap it in retry logic when it doesn't work instead of figuring out why it doesn't work. I have one case where my application behaves this way - it's when I have to call someone else's buggy legacy service that works 90% of the time and then fails randomly. In a sense doing this is like an admission of failure or acknowledgment of an unsolved problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have have to write a *lot* more (complex) code to make anything work the way you have laid out. It will be much more simple to just call a secondary method with a timeout.

And you should probably be running this as a separate thread, or you are going to "hang" your main processing thread during the "sleep" period.

On the whole, I would question whether or not you need to rethink your entire methodology.

```
public void Process(List<string> msg)
{
    bool permfail = false;
    bool complete = false;
    int runCount = 0;
    while (!complete && !permfail)
    {
        try
        {
            AttemptProcess(msg);
            complete = true;

        }
        catch
        {
            if (runCount++ > 10)
                permfail = true;
            else
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0));
        }
    }
}
void AttemptProcess(List<string> msg)
{
    // Do whatever processing here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, But just curios to know how complex to make it as attribute, and would it be  re-usability & separation of concern by making the retry mechanism as separate class, and use across the application, instead of catch and swallow the exception in each classes